# Creation of basic trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I wish for a trigger to fire and create a new payment when a new training session has been created. The Training object is being referenced but Salesforce displays the error;

"Error: Compile Error: Entity is not api accessible at line 1 column 1"

```
trigger createNewPayment on Training__c (after insert) {
    for(Training tra : Trigger.new){
        Payment__c newPayment = new Payment__c();

        newPayment.Payment_Received__c = FALSE;

        insert newPayment;
    }
}
```

I can't work out why this would not be working as I have created a similar trigger to create a new training session off the back of a new account being created. What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: User Training__c in the for loop than Training

Comment: Try to avoid using DML statements with in the for loop.And look on best practices in apex. @Glenn Daly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error is the usage of wrong API name without appending the __c with the custom object name in the for loop.

Change it to

```
trigger createNewPayment on Training__c (after insert) {
    List<Payment__c> lstPayment = new List<Payment__c>(); // List to hold the payments to be inserted
    for(Training__c tra : Trigger.new){
        Payment__c newPayment = new Payment__c();            
        newPayment.Payment_Received__c = FALSE;            
        lstPayment.add(newPayment); // add the payment to the list
    }
    insert lstPayment; // inser the list of payments
}
```

Bulkified your code to avoid 150 DML statement exception if the trigger executes in bulk of 200 records.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Gah. Please mention how to bulkify the dml, at least! You wrote the code in this answer, even if you copy-pasted it from the OP.